# In discrete models of spacetime, what are some implications of the Einstein equation

Tags: gravity, spacetime, quantum-gravity, discrete

We have several models of discrete spacetime.  Sorkin has a causal growth dynamics, there's spin foams, Panangaden showed a correspondence between interval domains and spacetimes.  I am looking for anything that looks like the Einstein equation.  Specifically, what are some required properties of a morphism of a spacetime (however it is modelled)?

Comment: A non-trivial model of "something" has to be able to predict some non-trivial properties of "something". What, exactly, can these things predict?